# Add a tag to multiple containers in GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'd like to use a single tag across different GTM containers. Did anyone manage to get a working solution?

Currently I duplicate the tag for each container.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a constant setup, the most effective way is to use the export/import functionality in Google Tag Manager. Admin > Container > Import/Export Container.

In addition, Simo Ahava released a GTM tool allowing for Google Tag Manager containers to be cloned to other containers: check out http://www.gtmtools.com/.

Comment: That's a nice idea. The tools allows adding tags from a container to a "cart" and apply that cart to other containers, effectively allowing easy cloning of tags from/to different containers.

Thanks for the effort however the original question still stands, hopefully there is a way.

Comment: Could you rephrase your original question? I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to create one tag that can be used across different containers. The end goal is to have a "single source of truth" to ease maintenance.

Comment: Why are you using multiple containers though? Is this across multiple different sites?

Comment: Yes, it is 3 different sites.

Comment: Why not install a single container across the three sites?